# Trying to remove everything that's not a letter or number, but keep the spaces

Tags: java, string

I'm using `"[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}\\p{IsDigit}]"` to remove anything that's not a number or letter, but it's also removing the whitespace. How to I keep the whitespace?

Comment: try adding a whitespace at the end of the []

Comment: I found a solution. Instead of deleting my question, let me post the solution in case anyone is struggling with this in the future:
I used: 
.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Instead of deleting my question, let me post the solution in case anyone is struggling with this in the future: I used:

```
 .replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "")
```